# call a method in model from View

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

I have successfully called a Method "GetDate"  from controller  "FreelancerProjects"  but with link ,I should hit link first to get result,but I want to get result directly with out link,how to do that?

calling method in view:

```
  <a title="الوقت" class="col-lg-2" style="color:grey;font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;">
                        <small>
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hourglass"></span>&nbsp; @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "GetDate", "FreelancerProjects", new { yourDate = item.DateOfRecord }, null);

                        </small>
                    </a>
```

the method in controller:

```
public string GetDate(DateTime yourDate)
{
    const int SECOND = 1;
    const int MINUTE = 60 * SECOND;
    const int HOUR = 60 * MINUTE;
    const int DAY = 24 * HOUR;
    const int MONTH = 30 * DAY;

    var ts = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks - yourDate.Ticks);
    double delta = Math.Abs(ts.TotalSeconds);

    if (delta < 1 * MINUTE)
        return ts.Seconds == 1 ? "one second ago" : ts.Seconds + " seconds ago";

    if (delta < 2 * MINUTE)
        return "a minute ago";

    if (delta < 45 * MINUTE)
        return ts.Minutes + " minutes ago";

    if (delta < 90 * MINUTE)
        return "an hour ago";

    if (delta < 24 * HOUR)
        return ts.Hours + " hours ago";

    if (delta < 48 * HOUR)
        return "yesterday";

    if (delta < 30 * DAY)
        return ts.Days + " days ago";

    if (delta < 12 * MONTH)
    {
        int months = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)ts.Days / 30));
        return months <= 1 ? "one month ago" : months + " months ago";
    }
    else
    {
        int years = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)ts.Days / 365));
        return years <= 1 ? "one year ago" : years + " years ago";
    }
}
```

Comment: If the "result" of that method is itself a View then it's not really clear what exactly you're trying to accomplish here.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: I want to get returned value of method directly with out link , now i get link when i click on link after that i get the returned value,that is because i have used "ActionLink" may be

Comment: But what is that "result"?  Is it just a value?  Or an entire view?  Expand on your example.  If it's just a value, from what business logic does it calculate that value?  Can the controller which returns this view invoke that same business logic?

Comment: @David thanks for your interesting first ...because  i am still bigginner , i have edited the question ,the result only value it is not entire view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're kind of thinking about it the wrong way.  You don't want to "call a controller method from a view", you want to invoke your logic *before returning your view* and include the result of that logic in the data being sent to the view.

Take a step back for a moment.  At this time you have two controller methods which need to invoke the same business logic.  That logic is currently in a controller, but it shouldn't be.  It should be in a model.  Consider a business model called `FreelancerProject`.  This logic can be added to that model, and since it doesn't rely on any state other than what's provided to it then it can be `static`:

```
public class FreelancerProject
{
    public static string GetDate(DateTime yourDate)
    {
        // your method logic
    }
}
```

Now your business logic is encapsulated in a model where it belongs.  Your existing `GetDate` controller method would then just return the result of that logic:

```
public string GetDate(DateTime yourDate)
{
    return FreelancerProject.GetDate(yourDate);
}
```

But now you can *also* invoke this business logic from other places as well.  (Technically you could when it was in a controller, but it would be unwieldy and start leading toward confusing code.)  Since it's `static` on a model, the simplest thing you can do is invoke it directly in your view:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hourglass"></span>&nbsp; @FreelancerProject.GetDate(item.DateOfRecord)
```

Though you *are* invoking this directly from a view, you're invoking *business logic* on a *model* rather than "calling a controller method".  It's a highly semantic but important difference.

As you move forward in your development, you're also likely to encounter business logic on your models that isn't `static`.  As the system gets more complex, you should move away from invoking that logic from within the view (the simplest possible approach in this one example above) and toward invoking it from within the controller method which returns that view.  The results of the business logic would populate a model, and that model would be sent to the view.  But *in the above extremely simplified case*, invoking a `static` method from within a view is technically acceptable, if skirting the line of semantically questionable.

Comment: thank you very much , we really need people like you,because you teach who need to learn ,thanks this is lecture not answer,Thanks for your patience with me